# What is the standard way of serializing records in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm dealing with custom records that I'd like to serialize to bytes. Is there a standard way to do this in OCaml?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Marshal`](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.13/api/Marshal.html) module.

Comment: ah interesting. Do you know if this is a deterministic algorithm? As in there is no ambiguity possible if hashing for cryptography?

Comment: I was told that this is mainly to serialize and deserialize types/functions in OCaml, but not a good fit for a protocol. It looks like binprot might be a good alternative